# Minecraft book duplicating

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I duplicate my books in Minecraft. I wrote a big story and I want to sell it on a server and I don't want to write the books one by one. Please help.

Comment: With Essentials and a helping (Admin-) hand you could do /more while holding the book. This will generate a full stack (16) of that item.

Comment: Is this a creative server?

Comment: Are you Op'ed on this server and can you enter creative mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This will only work If you have access to commands**

For starters you can use a book generator to generate your command and either place the command in the Minecraft text box or place your command in a command block.

a command looks something like this:

> /give @p written_book 1 0 {pages:["{\"text\":\"Hello
>   World!!!\"}"],title:"Create a book",author:Jason_,display:{Lore:["A
>   book to use multiple times"]}}

You can use a book generator like this: https://www.minecraftjson.com/

A book generator is not a mod and commands can be used in Vanilla Minecraft.

Make sure when you get to this page you click on the book tab.
[image]

There are few tutorials out there that I could find, but this one shout at least show the concept:

**If you are in creative mode**

if you are allowed into creative mode then what you could do is "scroll click" from a mouse and the book will be duplicated in a full stack.